# Can't figure out this perl string replace

Tags: regex, perl

I want to convert every occurrence of `"\\192.168.0.2\"` with `"q:\"`

So far I've come up with:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\\\\192.168.0.2\\/q:\\/' report.txt
```

This doesn't change anything in the file.  I could use some guidance!  Thanks

sample:
 file type  processed   10/29/2012 9:08:58 AM   \\192.168.0.2\reports\ report.xls

Comment: If you want to change 192.168.0.1, why does your re have 192.168.0.2?  Also, I think you want a double backslash at the end of the re.

Comment: I made a typo in my question, it should be .2 in both

Comment: Could you whow us sample lines from report.txt?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/\\\\192\.168\.0\.2\\/q:\\/" report.txt
```

Note the double quotes

Comment: For some reason this also does nothing to the file

Comment: Strange. Do you want to post a few lines from report.txt. It works for me

Comment: I can approximate a line:  file type processed 10/29/2012 9:08:58 AM \\192.168.0.2\reports\ report.xls

Comment: weird, I get no changes at all in the file

Comment: Is your file saved using a double byte encoding

Comment: According to notepad, just ANSI

Comment: Okay you want double quotes instead of single around the s/...//

Comment: You probably also want /g in case there's more than one match per line.

Comment: Yes it works now.  It was the fix offered in this answer which is why I picked it :)  The reason it wasn't working at first was because I failed to "note the double quotes" until it was pointed out.